# Unable to deliver attributes from JASIG CAS 3.5 using SAML 1.1

Tags: attributes, saml, cas, jasig

I am trying to configure a JASIG CAS 3.5 server to release attributes via SAML 1.1 as described [here](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/SAML+1.1).  Unfortulately, nothing I do seems to make it release them to my test application.

## CAS Server Configuration

I started by using the `StubPersonAttributeDao` that appears in the default configuration (DeployerConfigContext.xml).  My later attempts to set up a JDBC version did not produce any better results.

```
<bean id="attributeRepository"
        class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao">
        <property name="backingMap">
                <map>
                        <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
                        <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" /> 
                        <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
                </map>
        </property>
</bean>
```

I made sure that my test application was authorized to use CAS and that the attributes were allowed to it.

```
<bean
        id="serviceRegistryDao"
        class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl">
    <property name="registeredServices">
        <list>
            <!-- MIS Developers -->
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
                <property name="id" value="6" />
                <property name="name" value="Grails run-app" />
                <property name="description" value="JCC Developers can use this from any PC within the jccadmin domain." />
                <property name="serviceId" value="http://.*.my.domain:8080/.*" />
                <property name="evaluationOrder" value="6" />
                <property name="allowedAttributes">
                  <list>
                    <value>uid</value>
                    <value>eduPersonAffiliation</value>
                    <value>groupMembership</value>
                  </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The attributes are highlighted when you look at them in the CAS services application.

## The Tests

In order to learn whether my attributes were actually working, I created a [CAS testing application](https://github.com/ewcole/cas_tester) by using Gradle and the Jetty plugin to give flesh to the [sample code](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Saml11TicketValidationFilter+Example) on the JASIG website.  My application authenticates to the server and then makes a SAML 1.1 request to get the attributes.

I have verified that it is making the correct SAML request.

https://my.test.server/cas/samlValidate?TARGET=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.local.machine%3A8080%2Fcas_tester%2F

It receives the following response from my CAS server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol"
              xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"
              xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              IssueInstant="2017-02-01T14:40:35.328Z"
              MajorVersion="1"
              MinorVersion="1"
              Recipient="http://my.local.machine:8080/cas_tester/"
              ResponseID="_a0df351b1081dafe599829f406be79f5">
      <Status>
        <StatusCode Value="samlp:Success">
        </StatusCode>
      </Status>
      <Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"
                 AssertionID="_988118abbd06485ab7f1eb684639ce38"
                 IssueInstant="2017-02-01T14:40:35.328Z"
                 Issuer="localhost"
                 MajorVersion="1"
                 MinorVersion="1">
        <Conditions NotBefore="2017-02-01T14:40:35.328Z"
                    NotOnOrAfter="2017-02-01T14:41:05.328Z">
          <AudienceRestrictionCondition>
            <Audience>http://my.local.machine:8080/cas_tester/</Audience>
          </AudienceRestrictionCondition>
        </Conditions>
        <AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="2017-02-01T14:40:34.312Z"
                                 AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:unspecified">
          <Subject>
            <NameIdentifier>coleew01</NameIdentifier>
            <SubjectConfirmation>
              <ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:artifact</ConfirmationMethod>
            </SubjectConfirmation>
          </Subject>
        </AuthenticationStatement>
      </Assertion>
    </Response>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

No matter what I do, it doesn't show any attributes in the response.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was far away from the attribute configuration.  In my `credentialsToPrincipalResolvers` bean, there was no reference to the attribute resolver.

```
<property name="credentialsToPrincipalResolvers">
        <list>
                <!--
                        | UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports the UsernamePasswordCredentials that we use for /login 
                        | by default and produces SimplePrincipal instances conveying the username from the credentials.
                        | 
                        | If you've changed your LoginFormAction to use credentials other than UsernamePasswordCredentials then you will also
                        | need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations) to declare a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that supports the
                        | Credentials you are using.
                        +-->
                <bean
                        class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver"/>
                <!--
                        | HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports HttpBasedCredentials.  It supports the CAS 2.0 approach of
                        | authenticating services by SSL callback, extracting the callback URL from the Credentials and representing it as a
                        | SimpleService identified by that callback URL.
                        |
                        | If you are representing services by something more or other than an HTTPS URL whereat they are able to
                        | receive a proxy callback, you will need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations).
                        +-->
                <bean
                        class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" />
        </list>
</property>
```

I put a reference to the `attributeRepository` into the bean for the `UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver`.

```
<bean
        class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" >
    <property name="attributeRepository">
       <ref bean="attributeRepository"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then my attributes came through.  *Deo gratias!*